# Migrating Postgres to RDS

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, migrate

I currently have a Postgres DB (10.12) running in a docker container on a EC2 instance. I want to migrate the entire DB to RDS. What's the best way to do it? The additional docker container is complicating things. Not sure if I should use the AWS DMS or `pg_dumpall` command.

Comment: Is this production env ?

Comment: Yeah it is. But we're okay with the downtime.

Comment: First step, plan each and every step. Then develop test and validation processes for each step. Before implementation execute the entire plan including validations in a test environment. In other words don't rush, don't guess, take no step that you don't know the exact result before taking it.